# Android Google Translate QuickTranslateActiviy - Intent extra issue

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I want to use the QuickTranslateActiviy 
and I have tried this

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PROCESS_TEXT);        
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);     
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"String");     
i.setType(ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN);
i.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.google.android.apps.translate","com.google.android.apps.translate.QuickTranslateActivity"));
startActivity(i);
```

and It just keep showing the toast that could not find text. 
But the manifest of the Google translate here show that it accept plain text
[image]
had anyone try that before?Or am I doing it in a wrong way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tactically, you are using the wrong extra name. It should be `EXTRA_PROCESS_TEXT` or `EXTRA_PROCESS_TEXT_READONLY`, not `EXTRA_TEXT`.

Strategically, your implementation will break any time that the Google Translate app refactors their code or otherwise changes the fully-qualified class name of the activity.